# JQGrid searchrules and toolbar filtering error

Tags: jqgrid, filtering

I have a toolbar filter set up that works on a JQGrid of mine.  We recently got a requirement to only allow integers into this field.  I changed the colModel of the appropriate column in order to validate client side before a search takes place.  After making the changes to the javascript, the behavior has not changed.  Validation appears to not be taking place client side regardless of the input, which leads me to believe I have a misunderstanding of the search rules.  Code below

Previous

```
colModel:[ ...,
                      {name:'version', search:true, stype:'text'}
,...,]
```

Post Change

```
colModel:[ ...,
                      {name:'version', search:true, stype:'text',searchrules:{required:true, integer:true}}
,...,]
```

Do search rules not apply to toolbar filtering?  The documentation indicates that they would, unless I'm missing a line somewhere.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `searchrules` will be used only in the searching dialog, but not in the searching filter. As the workaround [beforeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) callback function for the validation of the data. You can analyse `this.p.postData`. If the searching data wrong you should display the error dialog do any other actions like adding 'ui-state-error' or 'ui-state-error-text' to the input with the wrong data and return `true`. `Returning`true`value from the`beforeSearch` handler will prevent applying the searching requests.

Comment: I think I have it working now.  Just have to get the appropriate error message to appear.  Thanks!

Comment: Does afterSearch get called regardless of if the search was triggered or not?  From what I can tell it does but I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Joseph: You can see from [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.custom.js#L189-192) that the current code of jqGrid call `afterSearch` independent from the value returned from `beforeSearch`.

Comment: I have a better solution to my original intent anyway in terms of displaying and removing any warning text if filtering fails.  I'll update my solution later today if I get time.

Comment: I am using before search option but I am getting whole table in 'this' object, can you suggest a way for the validation my datatype is local,
`jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, beforeSearch:function(data){console.log(this,data)}}).trigger("reloadGrid")`  @Oleg

Comment: @Vikas: It's better that you post new question, where you describe more detailed your problem, which version of jqGrid and from which fork you use and so on. The code `console.log(this,data)` make no sense. The callback `beforeSearch` have to return Boolean value, which informs jqGrid whether to process the filtering or to stop it. One should don't call any `trigge‌​r("reloadGrid")`. `this` is the table of cause, but it allow you access to any other options: `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters` is the filter, which you can analyse or modify.

Comment: @Oleg `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters` this helped , if I face any issue wil update it as new question